# How to deploy SharePoint 2013 Provider hosted app on Microsoft Azure and SharePoint 2013 On Premise?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I need to deploy SharePoint 2013 Provider hosted app on Microsoft Azure and SharePoint 2013 On Premise. The same app works well when deployed on Microsoft Azure and SharePoint 2013 Online, however I get SharePoint Context error in case of SharePoint on premise. app correctly redirects to azure site. any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mithun, I am trying to acheive this same behaviour as you did. But I am a new bee in both SharePoint Online and App creation. So can you please guide for how to make shaerpoint online app to be added in app catalog for the SharePoint 2013 onpremise.When I tried to add my SharPoint online app in SharePoint 2013, it has the value in appcat as Valdia app package as NO. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For on premise, you need to setup high trust app and generate client context using windows authentication since there is no token available for on premise.

Please find below steps to setup on premise app and troubleshooting steps

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shariq/archive/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-amp-troubleshooting-tips.aspx

Please provide error message

Comment: Thank you for taking time and helping me out.... really appreciate your help brother... I have already tried that... but it didn't work for me... I will update the post once i get the solution... :)

Comment: We ask that users not post link-only answers, because the link might stop working some day. Could you edit your answer to include a summary of the steps from the linked article?